# cross-platform keyboard and mouse detection

Tags: python, keyboard, cross-platform, mouse, detection

I am using PyCraft to create a small snake game in Minecraft, and I need to detect key presses or mouse clicks to control the movement of the snake. However, I have encountered a problem and I am unable to solve it.

I attempted to use the `keyboard` module, but it seems that it only works within the Python program itself. I also searched to see if PyCraft has built-in support for handling events, but I couldn't find any information. Additionally, I am using Windows as my operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the keyboard module, I recommend using **pynput**. Pynput allows you to not only detect key presses and mouse clicks, but also control them (virtual key presses and mouse clicks).

To detect mouse clicks:

```
from pynput import mouse

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format(
        'Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',
        (x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

And to detect key presses:

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

and that should work for you. You mentioned that the keyboard module only works in python itself, although I tested it, and it did work out of the program, so I would recommend showing your code on what you tried with the keyboard module, just in case there is something you overlooked. Pynput definitely works outside of the python program window.

This code was from https://pypi.org/project/pynput/, so if you need more information, I would recommend going there. There is also a link to the full documentation over there.

I would also recommend explaining a few more things, such as: "Does the keyboard and mouse detection need to be sychronized? Or do you need to detect the keyboard at a specific time, then the mouse at another?"

If pynput is not a solution for you still, then I do know that a mouse module exists, so at least you can get the mouse working but you'll have to figure out keyboard.